# X -configure doesn't work, [Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices]

Tags: debian, xorg, kde, x-server, intel-graphics

I have debian installed with KDE as the desktop environment, the following situation happened after I uninstalled nvidia-driver. There is no xorg.conf file so I run `sudo X -configure` to regenerate the file for my Intel driver. but I get the following error:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux Pavilion 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64 root=UUID=6394b397-de16-423b-93f0-536b2ef2ccba ro quiet
Build Date: 03 November 2018  03:09:11AM
xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Mar  8 10:44:22 2019
List of video drivers:
        amdgpu
        ati
        intel
        nouveau
        qxl
        vmware
        fbdev
        vesa
        modesetting
        radeon
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

** UPDATED **

Here is the generated logfile:

```
[   815.231] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[   815.231] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   815.231] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[   815.232] Current Operating System: Linux Pavilion 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64
[   815.232] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64 root=UUID=6394b397-de16-423b-93f0-536b2ef2ccba ro quiet
[   815.232] Build Date: 03 November 2018  03:09:11AM
[   815.232] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   815.232] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   815.232]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   815.232] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   815.232] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Mar  8 11:52:29 2019
[   815.232] (II) Loader magic: 0x55649976fe00
[   815.232] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   815.232]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   815.232]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[   815.232]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   815.232]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   815.232] (--) using VT number 2

[   815.232] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   815.233] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   815.233] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[   815.233] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   815.233] (EE) /dev/dri/card1: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[   815.234] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0a16:103c:2281 rev 11, Mem @ 0xb5000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00006000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   815.234] (--) PCI: (0:10:0:0) 10de:1341:103c:2281 rev 162, Mem @ 0xb3000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xb0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00003000/128
[   815.234] List of video drivers:
[   815.234]    amdgpu
[   815.234]    ati
[   815.234]    intel
[   815.234]    nouveau
[   815.234]    qxl
[   815.234]    vmware
[   815.234]    fbdev
[   815.234]    vesa
[   815.234]    modesetting
[   815.234]    radeon
[   815.234] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[   815.234] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[   815.234] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.234]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 1.2.0
[   815.234]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.234]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.234] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[   815.234] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[   815.234] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.234]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 7.8.0
[   815.235]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.235]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.235] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   815.235] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   815.235] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.235]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 2.99.917
[   815.235]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.235]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.235] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[   815.235] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[   815.235] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.235]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.13
[   815.235]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.235]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.235] (II) LoadModule: "qxl"
[   815.235] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/qxl_drv.so
[   815.235] (II) Module qxl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.235]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.1.4
[   815.235]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.235]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.235] (II) LoadModule: "vmware"
[   815.235] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
[   815.250] (II) Module vmware: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.250]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 13.2.1
[   815.250]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.250]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.250] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   815.250] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   815.250] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.250]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.4.4
[   815.250]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.250]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.250] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   815.250] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   815.250] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.250]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 2.3.4
[   815.250]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.251]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.251] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   815.251] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   815.251] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.251]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.19.2
[   815.251]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.251]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.251] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[   815.251] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[   815.251] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   815.251]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 7.8.0
[   815.251]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   815.251]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   815.251] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[   815.251] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[   815.251] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[   815.251] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[   815.251] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Sep 20 00:31:06 2016 -0400
[   815.251] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[   815.251]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[   815.251]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[   815.251]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[   815.251]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[   815.251]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[   815.251]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[   815.251]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[   815.251]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[   815.251]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[   815.251]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[   815.251]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[   815.251]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[   815.251]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[   815.251] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   815.251] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   815.251] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   815.304] (++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
[   815.304] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   815.304] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   815.304] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[   815.304] (**) |-->Screen "IntelScreen" (0)
[   815.304] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   815.304] (**) |   |-->Device "IntelDevice"
[   815.304] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "IntelDevice"
[   815.304] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Card0"
[   815.304] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Card1"
[   815.304] (==) No monitor specified for screen "IntelScreen".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   815.304] (**) Option "AutoAddGPU" "false"
[   815.304] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   815.304] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   815.304] (**) Not automatically adding GPU devices
[   815.304] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   815.305] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   815.305]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   815.305] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   815.305]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   815.305] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[   815.305] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   815.305] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   815.305] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20160919
[   815.305] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20161206-1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[   815.305] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[   815.305] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
[   815.305] (EE) Unknown chipset: NV118
[   815.305] Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
[   815.305] (EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[  1712.621] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
[  1712.621] (EE) Unknown chipset: NV118
```

The version of `nouveau` X11 driver in your Debian 9.x is too old to support your NVidia dGPU model. You might be able to proceed using the Intel iGPU only, if your hardware configuration allows that (i.e. the iGPU is physically wired to the displays/connectors you need; with multi-GPU Optimus laptops that may not always be true).

In most cases, a complete `xorg.conf` file is no longer necessary with modern versions of Xorg. You might get away with writing a mini-configuration file like `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/intel-only.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    Option "AutoAddGPU" "false"
    Screen 0 "IntelScreen"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "IntelDevice"
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
    Driver "intel" # or maybe "modesetting"?
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "IntelScreen"
    Device "IntelDevice"
EndSection
```

This would restrict the X server to use only the Intel iGPU and ignore the Nvidia dGPU for now, and to auto-detect all the input devices, display resolutions etc.

Comment: There's an Identifier missing in the first section, however I'm still getting the same error when I run `X -configure` afterwards. And I thought I needed xorg.conf because font rendering became small and not nice.

Comment: I updated the question (the log specifically) after putting this conf file in both directories.