Debian grub turn to older boot image instead of new broken
How is it possible to use an old boot image (6.1.0-18) as a default in grub and remove the newer one (6.1.0.-21) so far it's broken?
apt list -i 'linux-image*' gives
Listing... Done
linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64/stable,now 6.1.76-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-6.1.0-21-amd64/stable-security,now 6.1.90-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-amd64/stable-security,now 6.1.90-1 amd64 [installed]


you could ... apt remove the "broken" linux image - in what way is it broken though? In too many years to count, I've never had a broken linux image in stable Debian.

Something wrong with gpu driver and doesn't solve with reinstalling , see this [link] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/775456/debian-12-boot-fails-to-load-lightdm-and-stops?noredirect=1#comment1482277_775456)

apt remove the broken package also attempts to remove the metapackage linux-image-amd64 , which maylead to kernel panic if i take it correctly

the broken package - what broken package?

broken image linux-image-6.1.0-21-amd64
